# Why did I fail this audit? (Can no longer see the answer)

Tags: discussion, review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6611794

The answer no longer appears, but I recall it looking like a perfectly cromulent answer.  It may have been wrong, it was on a topic about which I know nothing, but it did appear to be an attempt to answer the question, so it didn't fit under any categorical reason for deletion that I could think of.

Comment: By itself that answer does look ok, but that user posted six answers linking to their site within a span of 2 hours. This was their only activity, so they were deleted as a spammer.

Answer (score 7):

The answer had been flagged as spam:

[image]

It might not be immediately obvious to everyone (so don't sweat that you failed the audit), but it clearly is spam - which would have been confirmed by checking their profile and what else they had posted on the site.

If you stay around the site for long enough you will see plenty more examples.

Comment: Where is the line between spam and a helpful tutorial link?   I don't see how the answer is spam.

Comment: @TabAlleman - it's really obvious to those of us who've been around a while - the text doesn't really address the question or it doesn't go into enough details, and the link is to a non-canonical site (as Martjin points out). It would be more obvious if the account hadn't been deleted - I could go and check their other posts, which would no doubt be of a similar nature to this one.

Comment: @ChrisF I disagree that it is obvious, I failed a similar audit (same user, different question). The answer while of questionable quality looked on topic and looked like an actual answer.

Answer (score 7):

The answer was a spam answer. To a 10k user the post is displayed as:

> This answer was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details.

and the source reads (link removed):

> If you are using Eclipse,You need to add and configure WebServer like Tomcat and to run the jsp file you need to right click on it and click on "Run on Server". If you are not using Eclipse then Place the .jsp file in the www/ or webapps/ folder of your Server. Restart the server. Open the file in the browser and you will get the desired output.
>
> To configure WebServer you can follow this tutorial: [spam link removed]

The post was made solely to promote the site, the account most likely spammed a large number of questions with that or similar answers. The account has since been destroyed.

Whenever you come across a post with a link that is *not* to a canonical documentation source but rather to a personal blog, you need to be very careful. Verify the post history of the account, verify the link (most of these sites are re-using plagiarised content). In case of an audit, the account check will already give you a huge hint something is afoot.

Had you encountered this post as an original (non-audit) review, the post history would have shown that this was someone using a shot-gun technique to pepper the site with links, and with an audit, the account would have given a 404 and the link to the original answer would have shown it to be deleted.

Comment: That's asking a lot of time spent on each review.  I think from now on I'll just be skipping any review that contains links I don't recognize.

Comment: Right, but take into account that one of the major goals of reviewing is to catch out posters like these. All it takes is a few extra clicks.

Comment: `That's asking a lot of time spent on each review.`  And that's a bad thing?  Are we in that much of a hurry to clear the queue of approximately 5 items?

Comment: @TabAlleman: if you cannot spend a minute or 2 on a single review here and there, you probably should reconsider why you are reviewing in the first place, to be honest.

Comment: I'm reviewing to help the site, but I'm not getting paid for it.  If I can tell in a glance whether a review deserves deletion (and 95% of the time I can), I'll vote.   Otherwise I'll skip, no biggie.